# MVC 2 ModelState - Show all Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2, modelstate

My asp.net form is throwing errors relating to an incorrect model, but on the page it's not showing me what model field threw the error. I'd like to Debug.WriteLine all errors in the ModelState but am unsure how to go about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't <%=Html.ValidationSummary()?> work?

Comment: haha thanks, I was using Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") ... didnt know it had several overloads

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe Html.ValidationSummary(true)! what the hell is the point in that? false means it should be displayed... good one